# How to extract a value by searching for two words in different lines and getting the value of second one

Tags: bash, sed, grep

How to search for a word, once it's found, in the next line save a specific value in a variable.

The json bellow is only a small part of the file.

Due to this specific file json structure be inconsistent and subject to change overtime, it need to by done via search like `grep` `sed` `awk`.

however the paramenters bellow will be always the same.

1. search for the word `next`
2. get the next line bellow it
3. extract everything after the word `page_token` not the boundary `"`
4. store in a variable to be used

###### test.txt:

```
"link": [
    {
      "relation": "search",
      "url": "aaa/ww/rrrrrrrrr/aaaaaaaaa/ffffffff/ccccccc/dddd/?token=gggggggg3444"
    },
    {
      "relation": "next",
      "url": "aaa/ww/rrrrrrrrr/aaaaaaaaa/ffffffff/ccccccc/dddd/?&_page_token=121_%_@212absa23bababa121212121212121"
    },
]
```

so the desired output in this case is:

```
PAGE_TOKEN="121_%_@212absa23bababa121212121212121"
```

my attempt:

```
PAGE_TOKEN=$(cat test.txt| grep "next" | sed 's/^.*: *//;q')
```

no lucky..

Comment: Use proper tools to parse json: `jq`

Comment: I agree that you need `jq`, but given your comment below, `sed -n '/next/{n;s/.*page_token=//p;q}' testDat` may  help, but is likely to blow up sooner than later. Good luck.

Comment: `sed -n '/"next",$/{N;s/^.*page_token=\([^"]*\)"/\1/;p}' file.txt` Enjoy...

Comment: If you cannot use a proper JSON parser, you might try something like: `p=$(grep 'page_token' test.txt); p="${p##*=}"; echo "PAGE_TOKEN=\"$p"`  or ` p=$(grep -A1 'next' test.txt); echo "$p"; p="${p##*=}"; echo "PAGE_TOKEN=\"$p"`

Comment: Thanks alot @Jetchisel, shellter and j_b.
all your answers worked.
would you be able to post it as the answer explaining how the command works.

I will accept as the answer

Comment: @Peter, I'll take a pass on posting a `sed` answer since there is already a `jq` one posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/next/{n;s/.*(page_token=)([^"]*).*/\U\1\E"\2"/p}' file
```

This is essentially a filtering operation, hence the use of the `-n` option.

Find a line containing `next`, fetch the next line, format as required and print the result.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your input is valid json, one option is to use:

```
cat test.json
[{
        "relation": "search",
        "url": "aaa/ww/rrrrrrrrr/aaaaaaaaa/ffffffff/ccccccc/dddd/?token=gggggggg3444"
    },
    {
        "relation": "next",
        "url": "aaa/ww/rrrrrrrrr/aaaaaaaaa/ffffffff/ccccccc/dddd/?&_page_token=121_%_@212absa23bababa121212121212121"
    }
]

PAGE_TOKEN=$(cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.relation=="next") | .url | gsub(".*=";"")')
echo "$PAGE_TOKEN"
121_%_@212absa23bababa121212121212121
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's a huge json which I only posted the part needed. One of the reasons I tried doing it with `grep` bc the json is super nested and it structure can can change

Comment: `jq -r ... test.json` without the `cat` maybe?

Comment: Definitely not insurmountable problems; here are some suggestions for when you're unsure of the structure and your file is large: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56892419/12957340